# Can I exclude a file from triggering a CI build in TFS?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have a assembly version file (SolutionAssemblyVersion.cs) which I keep at the root of my trunk in TFS.  I update this file and check it in during the build.  When I use the CI build in TFS it basically triggers another build as a result of that check in. Is there any way to exclude certain users from triggering a build?

I've seen Martin Woodward's TFS Top Tip #16 - Limit What you Build post but I'm hoping to not have to create a folder just for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out - add:

> ***NO_CI*** (3 stars)

to the front of your check-in comment.  Buck Hodges [blogged](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/tfs-2008-how-to-check-in-without-triggering-a-build-when-using-continuous-integration/) about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to hard code the string there is an MSBuild variable called $(NoCICheckInComment).